# How to split this String using mysql Query?

Tags: mysql, database

I have a table called "article"

```
ID       Date
1        3rd June 2017
2        2nd April 2016
3        21st June 2017
4        31st December 2015
```

and I want to find all the ID's where Date has June in it ,Therefore Result should be

```
ID
1
3
```

P.S -I tried doing this but I am stuck at this point , here is my Query

```
SELECT SUBSTRING_INDEX(SUBSTRING_INDEX(Date, ' ', 2), ' ', -1) as month
from article 
where article.month='June'
```

Comment: ummm... select id from article where date like '%June%'

Comment: can i pass "$abc" kind of variable in it? I am using php as well

Comment: Can you show us the php code as well? Also, if you run the query provided what is the result that you get?

Comment: Thank you everyone , i got what i wanted :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Why would you split the string to do that?

Just do:

```
where date like '%June%'
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use date functions in MySQL if you intend to make any more elaborate date comparisons later on:

```
select id from article where MONTH(STR_TO_DATE(Date,'%D %M %Y'))=6
```

where 6 corresponds to the 6th month (june).